# How do I send dms to a specific person.Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When my bot comes online I want it to dm me but it wont work. Heres the code.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    user = client.get_user(id)
    await user.send('bot online')
```

It says `nonetype has no attribute send`

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Comment: Have you invited your bot to your server before doing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = await member.create_dm()
    await channel.send("Bot is Online")
```

You have to make a dm through a channel not through a user

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can DM via User object: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user%20send#discord.User.send

Comment: @Booey It doesnt give an error message but it also doesnt dm me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_member` command to do this. If you want the bot to DM you specifically, you need to know your user ID, then inser it to a variable. Here is how you can define a simple command to DM someone ( for example you ) on bot startup:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    yourID = # Enter your ID here...
    discordUser = client.get_user(yourID)

    await discordUser.send('Bot online.')
```

Just in case you're not sure about how to get your ID, you can check out how to [get an ID](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-#:%7E:text=On%20Android%20press%20and%20hold,name%20and%20select%20Copy%20ID.).